# Means of expression in rock music

Tags: expression

I am a classical pianist and am trying to understand how the means of expression differ for the rock music. Examples:

1. In classic we usually have a very wide dynamics range. We play ppp to ffff. If you listen to rock, riffs are usually of the same dynamic. Drums are usually of the same dynamic range. If they suddenly play silently, the audio engineer is going to get panic, because the signal level is suddenly down in the mix. He will "fix" it to meet the dB level, and the dynamic range dies. Now, I am asking myself: if there is no dynamic in rock music in a classical sense, what there is instead?
2. A harpsichord has no dynamic range, as well. Instead, we use mini-breaks between the notes in order to make phrases and intonations. How does rock music deal with that, make phrases or intonations? Can you phrase a riff?
3. When adding reverbs or delays, the sound engineer adds loudness to the track. Does it mean, that a rock band is highly dependent on the sound engineer, - as the engineer actually changes the whole dynamic pallete?

In general, do you know scientific papers or maybe some Bachelor's thesis which have already covered that topic? The question is, what means of expression the rock music has? Especially, if compared to the classic music.

Do yoh have your own thoughts regarding this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141677/discussion-on-question-by-jupiter-jazz-means-of-expression-in-rock-music).

Answer (score 7):

> If you listen to rock, riffs are usually of the same dynamic

You have somewhat of a point there. But it's not that rock riffs are played without dynamics, more that they're typically played on distorted guitars. And [distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(music)) is a kind of dynamic compression, i.e. the loud- and softly-played parts of a guitar performance come out a lot more similar in volume than they would on an acoustic instrument.
But that doesn't mean the dynamics aren't there anymore: it's just that quiet notes, instead of having lower peak amplitude, instead are subdued in other ways – mellower overtones, quicker decay. And the guitarist can always also simply play shorter and/or fewer notes to achieve lower dynamic level.

> If they suddenly play silently, the audio engineer is going to get panic

Well, this is no different from classical music, really. If the flute suddenly plays silently, the conductor will also panic and needs to gesticulate to “fix” it. But that doesn't mean the dynamic range dies, and neither does it in case of rock drums. A good drummer will of course not suddenly play silently *without reason*, but they will absolutely play dynamically when there *is* a reason. Again, this often doesn't mean so much changing the peak sound pressure – the kick and snare drums are indeed expected to remain quite solid even in lower-dynamic passages, but if the drummer keeps the right hand on a gently-clicking closed hi-hat then it will still sound much more restrained than when she switches to crash cymbals and swooshing half-open hi-hat in the chorus. There's also a lot of dynamics on a smaller scale, e.g. ghost notes on the snare.

Guitarists additionally can employ a lot of dynamic variation from the electronic side: they may play a verse with a clean or only slightly crunchy sound, then switch to the amp's overdrive channel for the chorus, then add an extra distortion/booster pedal for the guitar solo.

> When adding reverbs or delays, the sound engineer adds loudness to the track

Not much. Reverb of course does change the *character*, and can make parts sound *bigger*, but not so much louder. Other effects that sound engineers add can indeed substantially affect loudness, in particular EQ and compression. So,

> a rock band is highly dependent on the sound engineer

– for sure, a bad engineer can ruin the gig even for a great band. But it's not so different the other way around: if the band plays bad, the sound engineer can only do so much. Live, at least; in the studio it has become ever more common for the sound engineer to “correct” and over-compress performances to death, with the result that on one hand mediocre drummers now sound ok on records, but on the other hand great drummers have little opportunity left to shine. It doesn't have to be this way though, there are plenty of examples of high-dynamic rock drumming. The sound engineer may still employ a lot of dynamic compression, it's not necessarily a bad thing: properly used, compression should still retain most of the dynamic *feeling*, but at the same time avoid de-emphasized notes getting lost in the mix.

In summary:

1. Dynamics through different sounds in different song passages. Examples:

   - Nirvana: *Smells Like Teen Spirit*
   - Scorpions: *Still Loving You*
2. Dynamics through sparsity/denseness. Examples:

   - AC/DC: *Back In Black*
   - Yes: *Roundabout*
3. Dynamics through playing techniques and phrasing. Examples:

   - Led Zeppelin: *The Ocean*
   - Deep Purple: *Burn*
4. You *can* also have simply dynamics as loudness variations. Often this entails sound changes and/or that some instruments drop out completely during the quiet parts, but again, this isn't so different in classical music. Examples:

   - Pink Floyd: *The Great Gig in the Sky*
   - Led Zeppelin: *What Is and What Should Never Be*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141706/discussion-on-answer-by-leftaroundabout-means-of-expression-in-rock-music).